# Remove Labels and Tick-marks from Colorbar in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a heatmap and I want to remove the labels and tickmarks on the colorbar. How can I do this with the heatmap I've made so far (code below)?

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.heatmap(my_heatmap, cmap='RdYlGn', vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8, 6)
plt.title('10 mm Precipitation Probabilities\nTopeka, Kansas', fontsize = 16)
plt.xlabel('X', fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel('Y', fontsize = 14)
plt.text(6.7,.18, 'High Probability')
plt.show()
```

[image]

(I would rather it just say *High Probability* at the top of the bar as shown with the label I made).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56094845/matplotlib-remove-the-ticks-axis-from-the-colorbar

Comment: @BigBen this is not helpful as I plotted my heatmap in a different way. See the code I provided in the question.

Comment: Definitely is helpful, you just need to access the colorbar Axes and then apply that solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the colorbar via `cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar` (see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820239/seaborn-heatmap-colorbar-label-as-percentage)).

Then, you can change the ticks (`cbar.set_ticks([])`) or set new ticks and new tick labels:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8, 6)
my_heatmap = np.random.rand(10, 10)
ax = sns.heatmap(my_heatmap, cmap='RdYlGn', vmin=0, vmax=1)
# ax.get_figure().set_size_inches(8, 6)
ax.set_title('10 mm Precipitation Probabilities\nTopeka, Kansas', fontsize=16)
ax.set_xlabel('X', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('Y', fontsize=14)
cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.set_ticks([0, 0.5, 1])
cbar.set_ticklabels(['Low\nProbability', 'Average\nProbability', 'High\nProbability'])
# cbar.set_label('Probability')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Note that `plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]` doesn't change the size of the figure, but sets the default size for the next figure that will be created. So you need to call it before `sns.heatmap` which creates a new figure if none was created before. To change the size of an already-created figure, use `set_size_inches()`.